# Prove that the roots of $2x^3 - x + 5 = 0$ are irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

We want to prove that for the equation $2x^3 -x + 5 = 0$, any root must be irrational. How can this be done? Seems like plugging in $x = a/b$ doesn't really help at all.

Answer (score 3):

The rational root test implies that, if $\frac{r}{s}$ is a root of $2x^3 - x + 5$ (in lowest terms), then $r \mid 5$ and $s \mid 2$.  Thus, $r = \pm 1, \pm 5$ and $s = \pm 1, \pm 2$. These are the only possible rational roots.  Plugging in each value shows that there are indeed no rational roots.